# Rails replace one hash by another if keys exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't know what's going on but I've got two hashes:

`first_hash`

```
{
  'Ids' => ['string_first_hash'],
  'Description' =>
  {
    'Url' => 'some_path',
    'EventCallback' => {
      'Url' => 'some_path',
      'WhiteList' => ['string'],
    },
    'Steps' => [{
      'OrderIndex' => 1,
      'Recipients' => [
        {
          'Email' => 'email@first.hash',
          'FirstName' => 'first_hash_name',
          'LastName' => 'first_hash_last_name',
          'LanguageCode' => 'en',
        },
      ],
    }],
  },
}
```

And the second one:

`template_hash`

```
{
  'Ids' => ['template_stirng'],
  'Description' => {
    'Name' => 'Template_name',
    'Subject' => 'template_subject',
    'Finish' => false,
    'Steps' => [{
      'OrderIndex' => 1,
      'Recipients' => [
        {
          'Email' => 'Placeholder =>',
          'FirstName' => '',
          'LastName' => '',
          'LanguageCode' => '',
          'DisableEmail' => false,
          'IdentificationMethods' => [],
        },
      ],
      'RecipientType' => 'Signer',
    }],
  },
}
```

Now I want to add `first_hash` to the `template_hash` and override only those key/value which exist in both and leave the rest from second_hash unchanged (should be added in the result). I thought all I want to do is:

`test = first_hash.merge(template_hash)`

But the result is surprising - nothing change, it prints second hash unchanged:

```
> test
{"SspFileIds"=>["7fcf6021-386d-4f31-a871-a89afb8fb36e"],
 "SendEnvelopeDescription"=>
  {"Name"=>"1 Recipient",
   "EmailSubject"=>"Please sign the enclosed envelope",
   "EmailBody"=>"Dear #RecipientFirstName# #RecipientLastName#\n\n#PersonalMessage#\n\nPlease sign the envelope #EnvelopeName#\n\nEnvelope will expire at #ExpirationDate#",
   "DisplayedEmailSender"=>"",
   "EnableReminders"=>true,
   "FirstReminderDayAmount"=>5,
   "RecurrentReminderDayAmount"=>3,
   "BeforeExpirationDayAmount"=>3,
   "DaysUntilExpire"=>28,
   "StatusUpdateCallbackUrl"=>"",
   "LockFormFieldsAtEnvelopeFinish"=>false,
   "Steps"=>
    [{"OrderIndex"=>1,
      "Recipients"=>
       [{"Email"=>"Placeholder:",
         "FirstName"=>"",
         "LastName"=>"",
         "LanguageCode"=>"",
         "DisableEmail"=>false,
         "AddAndroidAppLink"=>false,
         "AddIosAppLink"=>false,
         "AddWindowsAppLink"=>false,
         "AllowDelegation"=>true,
         "AllowAccessFinishedWorkstep"=>false,
         "SkipExternalDataValidation"=>false,
         "AuthenticationMethods"=>[],
         "IdentificationMethods"=>[]}],
      "RecipientType"=>"Signer"}]}}
```

What's going on, am I misunderstand something? I'm using Rails 7 and Ruby 3.

**[EDIT]**

`expected_result`

```
{
  'Ids' => ['string_first_hash'],
  'Description' => {
    'Name' => 'Template_name',
    'Subject' => 'template_data_string',
    'Finish' => false,
    'Steps' => [{
      'OrderIndex' => 1,
      'Recipients' => [{
        'Email' => 'email@first.hash',
        'FirstName' => 'first_hash_name',
        'LastName' => 'first_hash_last_name',
        'LanguageCode' => 'en',
      }],
      'RecipientType' => 'Signer',
    }],
    'Url' => 'some_path',
    'EventCallback' => {
      'Url' => 'some_path',
      'WhiteList' => ['string'],
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting the result to look like?

Comment: @muistooshort question updated

Comment: @mechnicov I want to override it. The issue is that both `merge` and `deep_merge` stop working after "Steps" = [ { ... } ]` because result doesn't contain anything else after this `Steps` array of hashes. In this case `"RecipientType" => "Signer"` is not included in the end result. I've got over 100 different hash keys after that `Steps` array of hashes which I want to add to the end result.

Comment: @mechnicov Because I want to have data from `first_hash` in `second_hash`. Like I described in my post.

Comment: Would you mind simplifying your input and expected output examples? It would be much easier to understand your requirements and the differences when one could see all three hashes at the same time without scrolling.

Comment: @spickermann Alright, question updated and I changed the `second_hash` to the `template_hash` - hope it will be simpler to understand. I cannot simplify anything more because you can tell me - hey, use `deep_merge!` and that's not the answer. In such nested objects `deep_merge` gets completely lost.

Comment: @mr_muscle you are merging hash in wrong hash - you should do this -> `template_hash.deep_merge_overrirde(first_hash)`

Comment: but if you need nested hash merge which includes nested array of hash then
you will need custom solution - you can refer [this post](https://www.jvt.me/posts/2019/09/07/ruby-override-merge-nested-array-hash/)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `deep_merge`? https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge

What you want is
`test = first_hash.deep_merge(second_hash)`

Comment: No, that's not true. Check on your end what you've got